# is there any tool for automatic interface generation using swig?

Tags: c++, python, interface, swig

I have a project running in c++. I want to create a python wrapper for the classes and some global functions.

I am wondering if there is any tool for generating the interface file for swig automatically?

Secondly, it is very easy to write the interface file for functions. But for classes, are there any design patterns which must be followed for clean interface generation?

Thanks a lot

Comment: SWIG doesn't always require interface files -- it can parse the headers itself.  I suggest to read the [SWIG tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html).

Comment: @Sven Marnach, thanks for your suggestion. I was wondering if there is any tool which can parse whole of the project. After all the interfaces will be created. I want to instantiate the instances and establish necessary interaction.